# Compiler failing, but no error lines detected

Tags: jgrasp

I use jgrasp, but when I try to run a project it says "Compilation failed, but no error lines were detected. Check for non-clickable errors in compilation output." I have the JDK, not just the JRE. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As it says, check the compiler output for non-clickable errors. Most likely there is some message in the output that will tell you what went wrong. Clickable errors are compilation errors in the format that javac uses.

Occasionally javac spits out a non-standard-format error for some unusual condition. For example, recent versions of javac do not properly handle OneDrive on-demand files, and will report "javac: not a file ...". If that is what is happening, you will need to change the OneDrive settings to turn on-demand off, or copy the files to a local folder to work on them then back to the OneDrive folder when you are done.

Other possibilities are that javac is crashing due to a bug, or that you have some other "javac" that is running instead of the actual Java compiler. You can turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages" in jGRASP and compile to verify that the correct "javac" is being invoked.